Pairwise Welch T-Test, Kruskal-Wallis, or other?
I am conducting an analytical chemistry experiment in which I have 11 groups of experimental (environmental samples, 11 sites), 1 Lab control, and 3 Field Controls. All groups have 3 observations for the specific chemical, except one of the field controls which only has 2.
I would like to know if the observed value of a certain environmental sample site differs from that of the control(s).
I am not sure the best way to do this and have got completely different answers from: 2 PhD Advisors
1 Grad student 1 Fellow Ugrad
To compare a site to the control(s) should I compare:
(a) Combine the 4 controls into one group and do a Welch T-Test against the Environmental Sample
(b) Combine the 3 controls (sans control with only two replicates) into one group and do a Welch T-Test against the Environmental Sample
(c) Analyze the 3 or 4 controls + Environmental sample in a Kruskal-Wallis test (3 observations are oftentimes not normal)
(d) Compare the Lab Control to the Environmental Site in a Welch T-Test
(e) Report multiple of these tests?
Using a significance of P = 0.05 I have done methods A, C, and D and have come up with very different answers to my hypothesis.
Edit:


Edit for clarity:
The response variable is a measured environmental concentration of chemicals of interest, which is available for 11 sites, 3 field controls, and one lab control in replicates of 3 = 44 observations + (1) lost replicate. This is available for 8 compounds giving 352 total measurements.
The data is non-normal because different sites produce different measurements, and pollution does not follow a normal distribution in this small of a sample (some sites are well polluted, most not) but the machinery used to measure such concentrations should produce a Gaussian distribution if testing the same sample for the same compound in replicate.
The instrumentation has a bottom Limit Of Detection (LOD) which leads to many 0's within the dataset, which in my experience up until now limit the ability of the data to transform to normality.
I am not sure how to list the entire dataset here but I have included a box-plot that include Kruskal-Wallis results for a single compound across multiple sites here since that's what the discussion has been focused on.


You have asked this question earlier, haven't you? Please don't engage in such actions. Edit your previous post to respond to any possible feedback instead of asking the same thing by deleting the previous one.

I don't know what kind of feedback you got in the previous instance of your question, but perhaps you should clarify if you're interested in comparing the experimental group to all controls taken as a whole, or the experimental group vs. each control taken individually. It's not clear from your question. Also, why are you using a parametric test like the Welch t-test, and then a non-parametric test like the Kruskal-Wallis test? Are there some assumptions you're making about your data that you don't mention in your question?

Also, as @User1865345 mentioned, don't delete and repost a question. Edit it instead, to add relevant information and to address the problems people may have pointed out to you. There's a link for editing a question, that is just under the question and above the comments. Otherwise, if you delete a question, we lose all the comments that people may have posted under it, so there's a risk that we will all waste our time having the same discussion again.

Hi @User1865345, I deleted and reposted as there was a typo in my previous question. I wasn't tryibg to dodge any previous advice, onky implementing some advice to fix the post. Thanks for pointing out the proper etiquette.

@J-J-J Youre asking me some questions I was looking for advice on myself as im new to statistics and hypothesis testing. [1] I think its most appropriate to compare to one control (the Lab Control) but I want some thought on how to compare to all controls (and if thats appropriate) and how I could do that. Whether by grouping them into one group or using something ANOVA adjacent. [2] Valid criticsm, my PI suggested a parametric test such as T test for a single comparison as data is assumed to be normal, but shapiro-wilk normality tests show ~50% of the data non-normal.

The instrumentation used to measure values is assumed to create a normal spread, hence my PI's argument a parametric test is appropriate.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Xeniidae As it looks like you've taken advice from other people before asking your question here, they should have given you some rationale as to why using such and such method. It would be very helpful to edit your question to mention what they said, as it can reveal something important about your data and study design that you omitted to mention here.

If your previous question had a typo the correct action is to edit it, not delete it

Many details are missing here that would allow suggestions of good analyses. The outcome or response variable is left vague but is perhaps concentration of some chemical. I'd expect such a variable to be markedly skew and likely better analysed on a logarithmic scale, but there could be other problems too e.g. detection limits. Unless there are confidentiality issues there is no obvious reason why you should list the entire dataset.

Hi @NickCox , I clarified the information you were discussing via an edit in the original post. I would be happy to provide the dataset to you should have interest but I'm not sure how to do that here.

Thanks for the extra detail. A listing of the data can be just any listing of observations that allows copy and paste. What you show includes a massive outlier group. Falling below detectable limits certainly causes problems: you can't even be certain that the zeros deserve the same rank.

Please do not take this personally, but this kind of question brings to mind the following quote from R. Fisher

To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of. -- Ronald Fisher (1938)

Let's start with the title of the question "Pairwise Welch T-test". There is simply no such thing; if it is a paired t-test, then it is a single-sample t-test, which has no Welch "flavor". If it is a Welch t-test, then it is for 2 independent samples (not paired).
Let's now talk about the controls; it is unclear why it was felt necessary to have both field controls, and a lab control? It should be assumed that the conditions for the field controls and the lab control are different? About the only thing I can think off is that the lab control is a control for the field controls (??). OK, then combine all your 3 field controls (including the one with only 2 observations), and compare this with the lab control (2-sample Welch t test), and see if there is a difference.
Now, whether there is, or not, it is unclear what different direction you would take. I would simply ignore the lab control (as it adds a nuisance variable -field vs. lab).
Let's now tackle the sample size; you say each site has only 3 observations. This is about the smallest sample size anyone could try to use. You are now "up the creek without a paddle". The study has very low power, and unless the effects are very large (so large in fact that they probably do not even need any statistical test; just plot the data!), you will likely get no significant result, and if by chance you get one, it is most likely going to be a false positive.
Now, are the 11 sites really different, and you are interested in differences between them? If not, you could combine all 11 sites into a single "field" sample; your sample size now gives you some hopes (via a Welch t-test).
You now say that you tried (a), (c) and (d) and got very different results. It should not be surprising as t-tests test against a null of equality of the means, while Kruskal-Wallis tests test against a null of stochastic equality. The 2 do not test the same thing, so they do not give the same result.
Moving on to normality. Looking at the normality of each sample, which only have 3 observations is an exercise in futility. You can not eyeball normality, nor can you trust any test of normality (significant or not) with such small sample sizes.
Now, which test? The most obvious one would be one not even mentioned in the question, a one-way ANOVA. Compare all 11 experimental siteswith the mixture of the field controls (ignoring the lab control). The key assumption for this ANOVA is the normality of the residuals (not of the marginal distributions). The residuals will have 41 observations; there a normality test (Shapiro-Wilk?) may be trusted (some even would argue not to bother, but let's see if it at least the residuals look not too non-normal). That would tell you if there is any difference in means. After that, if ANOVA is significant, you can use the Dunnett multiple comparisons with a control, to see which site differs significantly from the control.
If you are really bothered by non-normality (I would not, not with 3 observations per sample), or if the residuals are seriously skewed, you could run a Kruskal-Wallis of all 11 sites against the mixture of field controls, followed by Dunn's post-hoc test.. But remember that Kruskal-Wallis tests for something different than ANOVA, or t-tests (which test for differences in means).

Hi! First of all, thanks for responding. Let me clear up some confusion with my original information:
[1] I misused the word "pairwise", but it is now irrelevant.
[2] Yes, the lab control controls for the field control. This is because we were testing for differences in the amounts of contamination that could have occurred between the field laboratory and the university laboratory.
[3] My main objective is to tell if there is a significant difference between the environmental sample and the control(s). It seems the ANOVA with a Dunnet comparison to just the control can achieve this.

my follow-up question, after some thought and EDE is if an ANOVA is appropriate here because I am only concerned about if difference between each  site and the control (or controls), and by including the other sites their variability is factored into that question.

ANOVA will tell you if at least 1 factor is different from at least another 1. So yes, it could be significant because 2 sites are different from each other. But this is where Dunnet comparison comes into play, because it compares to whchever group you designate as the "control". Because it runs fewer comparisons, it preserves more power. If your alternative  is that the contamination is greater in the field than the control, you can run Dunnett at 90% confidence (thus simulating single sided tests, to conserve even more power); you will need this with only 3 observations in each group.

Thank you so much!

How do you define residuals that are "Seriously Skewed". Shaprio-Wilk of the ANOVA residuals comes up with a P-Value of 2.56E-06. I've also included a QQ plot and ANVOVA results in the original post.

Well, based on the Q-Q plot (and the p-value), your residuals are not normal, and are a pretty bad case of it (positively skewed, but heavy tails on both sides...). So ANOVA is problematic here. But Kruskal-Wallis may not get you any significant result (no matter how different) with only 3 samples per group; groups would need to pretty much be non-overlapping. Back to the small sample size issue...
